# Git crashes on Xcode on push or pull attempt

Tags: xcode, git

I have been using the command line instead of Xcode since it seems to work better.  However, I recently went to Xcode to do a simple push.  Something must have got messed up during it because the data never got pushed.  Now, whenever I try in Xcode to push or pull, it automatically quits.

When I go to the command line and do a git status, it says I am on this branch, but nothing out of the ordinary.  When I try to do

```
git branch -a
```

It lists my branches, but does not have the * telling me I'm on this branch.  That's all I can tell from what's out of the ordinary.  Any thoughts on what I can do to recover?  My changes aren't that big so I can just redo the code.  Just annoying and it'd be helpful to know what is wrong and how to avoid this in the future. Thanks!

Comment: have you tried doing a checkout of your branch to mark it as the current?